# Can a polynomial family of curves be identified by a polynomial satisfied by its derivatives?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, differential-equations

Suppose we have a 1-parameter family of curves that foliate a subset of the plane, defined by a function that is a polynomial in the coordinates $(x,y)$ and a parameter that identifies the individual curves.

For example, the family of curves defined by:

$$P(x,y,a) = 16 a^2 \left(x^2+y^2-a^2\right)-\left(2 x_f x +y_f\left(2 y-y_f\right) -x_f^2\right) \left(8 a^2+2 x_f x+2 y_f y-x_f^2-y_f^2\right) = 0$$

is the set of confocal ellipses with foci at $(0,0)$ and $\left(x_f,y_f\right)$, with the parameter $a$ giving the semi-major axis of each ellipse.

Associated with this family of curves is a field of tangents to the curves:  at each point $(x,y)$ a unique curve passes through the point, and if we choose an orientation we can assign a unit vector to each point that is tangent to that curve.

We can derive a polynomial equation satisfied by the components of these tangent vectors, $(x',y')$ along with the coordinates $(x,y)$, by supposing we have parameterised each curve as $\left(x_a(t),y_a(t)\right)$ then taking the derivative of $P(x_a(t),y_a(t),a)$ with respect to $t$, to produce a polynomial $D(x,y,x',y',a)$. In our example, we have:

$$D(x,y,x',y',a)=16 a^2 \left(2 x x'+2 y y'-x_f x'-y_f y'\right)-4 \left(2 x_f x+2 y_f y-x_f^2-y_f^2\right) \left(x_f x'+y_f y'\right)$$

When $P$ and $D$ are both zero their resultant with respect to $a$ will be zero, and we have:

$$Res_{a}(P,D) = \left(y'\right)^4 \left(2 x^3 x_f \left(2 y-y_f\right) y_f+x^2 \left(x_f^2 \left(-2 y y_f+y_f^2-4 y^2\right)+y_f^2 \left(y_f-2 y\right){}^2\right)+2 x y^2 x_f \left(2 x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)-y^2 x_f^2
   \left(x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)\right){}^2+\left(x'\right)^4 \left(2 x^3 x_f \left(2 y-y_f\right) y_f+x^2 \left(x_f^2 \left(-2 y y_f+y_f^2-4 y^2\right)+y_f^2 \left(y_f-2 y\right){}^2\right)+2 x y^2 x_f
   \left(2 x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)-y^2 x_f^2 \left(x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)\right){}^2-4 \left(x'\right)^3 y' \left(x^3 \left(2 y-y_f\right)+x^2 x_f \left(y_f-3 y\right)+x y \left(x_f^2+3 y
   y_f-y_f^2-2 y^2\right)+y^2 x_f \left(y-y_f\right)\right) \left(2 x^2 x_f y_f-x \left(x_f^2 \left(y_f+2 y\right)+y_f^2 \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)+y x_f \left(x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)\right){}^2+4 x'
   \left(y'\right)^3 \left(x^3 \left(2 y-y_f\right)+x^2 x_f \left(y_f-3 y\right)+x y \left(x_f^2+3 y y_f-y_f^2-2 y^2\right)+y^2 x_f \left(y-y_f\right)\right) \left(2 x^2 x_f y_f-x \left(x_f^2 \left(y_f+2 y\right)+y_f^2
   \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)+y x_f \left(x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)\right){}^2+2 \left(x'\right)^2 \left(y'\right)^2 \left(-4 x^3 x_f+x^2 \left(2 x_f^2+8 y y_f-y_f^2-8 y^2\right)+y^2 \left(2
   \left(y-y_f\right){}^2-x_f^2\right)+2 x y x_f \left(4 y-3 y_f\right)+2 x^4\right) \left(2 x^2 x_f y_f-x \left(x_f^2 \left(y_f+2 y\right)+y_f^2 \left(y_f-2 y\right)\right)+y x_f \left(x_f^2+y_f \left(y_f-2
   y\right)\right)\right){}^2$$

So we have eliminated the parameter $a$ to obtain a homogenous polynomial in $(x',y')$ that will be zero for any field of tangents to the curves, since any multiple of $(x',y')$ will also yield zero.

My question is: when and how can this construction be reversed?  Given a polynomial $R(x,y,x',y')$ like this that is satisfied by a field of tangents, is there a test that can determine whether it originated from a polynomial family of curves?  And can the defining polynomial be reconstructed?

If we write down a polynomial $P$ of a sufficiently high degree, with unknown coefficients, we can carry through this whole construction to produce a resultant polynomial, which we could then attempt to match with our given $R(x,y,x',y')$ by solving a potentially very large number of polynomial equations in the unknown coefficients.

So my question is: can we do better than that brute-force approach?

For the specific case I’m trying to solve, I have a polynomial satisfied by the tangent vectors that is of degree 8 in the derivatives and degree 6 in the coordinates.

Note that there is a **symmetry** between the coefficients of the derivatives in the resultant in the example:  if the terms are given by $C_{i,j}(x')^i(y')^j$, we have

$$C_{i,j} = (-1)^{i}C_{j,i}$$

The $R(x,y,x',y')$ that I wish to integrate also has this symmetry.

This is not a property of the resultant obtained from a generic polynomial $P(x,y,a)$, or even from a generic foliation; for example, $P(x,y,a)=(x^2+1)a-y$ foliates the plane with parabolas, but yields the resultant $R(x,y,x',y')=2 x y x' - (x^2+1) y'$.

**Edited to add:** The symmetry in the coefficients of the resultant for the family of confocal ellipses can be explained by the well-known fact that the same family extends to the family of confocal hyperbolas, with both an ellipse and a hyperbola passing through every point in the plane, **with orthogonal tangents**.

Since we have eliminated the parameter $a$ from the resultant, it must be zero for both parameter values at each point, and the symmetry in the coefficients yields:

$R(x,y,-y',x') = \pm R(x,y,x',y')$

which is sufficient to ensure that if $R$ is zero for one tangent, it is also zero for the orthogonal tangent.

Comment: There is not much one can say.  For example, consider the simplest case:  A *linear* relation between the differentials with polynomial coefficients, i.e., $$\omega = P(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x + Q(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y = 0.$$  You want a test for when there is an algebraic first integral, i.e, when there is a nonzero algebraic $M(x,y)$ such that $\mathrm{d}\bigl(M(x,y)\omega\bigr) = 0$, i.e., an algebraic integrating factor. There are certainly necessary conditions at the singular points (i.e., points where both $P$ and $Q$ vanish), but I'm not aware of any general sufficient conditions.